# Angular - Can't resolve 'croppie' in node_modules\ngx-croppie\esm5

Tags: angular, angular-components, croppie

I'm trying to add a croppie to my Angular project, and by following this link:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-croppie
```

I executed this command :

```
npm i ngx-croppie
```

And this added croppie and ngx-croppie to my project in node_modules,
but now I'm facing next error:
And Indeed when I open my component, there is a this issue:

And in my node_modules there is no croppie folder but in `node_modules/@types/` croppie exist as in next image:

Answer (score 1):

please uninstall `ngx-croppie` package and again install `npm install ngx-croppie@1.0.1`package and then install npm install.