# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'croppie' in

Tags: javascript, angular, crop

I'm building an application on Angular 6 which uses the [ngx-croppie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-croppie) module. It was working fine, however when I'm doing

> ng build --prod

I'm getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'croppie' in '/node_modules/ngx-croppie/esm5'
```

Any clues how this can be solved? The ngx-croppie version is 1.1.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to install another `croppy` version as noted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253559/angular-cant-resolve-croppie-in-node-modules-ngx-croppie-esm5

Comment: @SergiiVorobei That's the same for ANY version literally.

Comment: have you got croppie in package.json ... npm i --save ngx-croppie will add it

Comment: @danday74 It's there. The problem is not in the package.json.

Comment: what build options are you using for prod build? they are defined in angular.json - turning off aot sometimes helps

Comment: @danday74 If I disable "aot", I won't be able to use "buildOptimizer". Nevertheless, the issue still exists if I even disable "aot" and "buildOptimizer".

Comment: is croppie in your package-lock file?

Comment: @danday74 Yes, it's there along with the types.

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved.

Had to include this in dependencies in package.json:

```
"croppie": "2.6.2"
```

And then do:

```
npm install
```